# could not build arguments for function

Tags: go, dependency-injection

I am trying to build go application using DI but since I just started to learn how to do this I am facing problem as below

"could not build arguments for function "github.com/pharmeasy/kite/service/handlers".CreateExperiment.func1 (/Users/sahilpaudel/Documents/PharmEasy/Go/kite/service/handlers/experiment.go:62): failed to build *repository.ExperimentRepository: missing dependencies for function "github.com/pharmeasy/kite/core/dao/repository".NewExperimentRepository (/Users/sahilpaudel/Documents/PharmEasy/Go/kite/core/dao/repository/experiment.go:16): missing type: *string"

repository looks like this

```
type ExperimentRepository struct {
    dbName *string
}

// NewExperimentRepository returns new ExperimentDao
func NewExperimentRepository(dbName *string) *ExperimentRepository {
    return &ExperimentRepository{ dbName: dbName }
}


func (expRepo *ExperimentRepository) Create(experiment *models.Experiment) error {
    return nil
}
```

DI looks like this

```
func buildContainer() *dig.Container {
    container := dig.New()
    _ = container.Provide(config.NewConfig)
    _ = container.Provide(database.GetInstance)
    _ = container.Provide(repository.NewExperimentRepository)
    return container
}
```

And I am trying to use it here as

```
di := container.GetInstance()

    err = di.Invoke(func(experimentRepo *repository.ExperimentRepository) {
        err := experimentRepo.Create(&experiment)
        if err != nil {
            utils.RespondError(res, err, http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return 
        }
    })
```

Stucks since morning and but couldn't figure out whats the issue here.

Comment: The `dbName *string` is probably an "unmet" dependency, or it's "ambiguous". How exactly do you instruct the `dig` container which `*string` it should pass to `NewExperimentRepository`? And where in your code *is* the `*string` value that `dig` should feed to your constructor?

Comment: I'm having similar error as well. Have you found the solution?